# Deleting rows of data after checkout

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete the data on my `cart` table after the customer decided to checkout. Basically the reason why I want it removed from the table is to reset all of the Total Items and Total Price.

So far, I've tried adding this after the `$run_sales = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sales);` :

`if($run_sales){
mysqli_query($con, "delete * from cart where orderId = '$sales_itemid'");
}`

I provided an else statement that would show an error but it seems like it's not making an error. But the row is not getting deleted. Where and What do I need to add on my code for that?

```
<?php 
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");
        if(isset($_SESSION['customer_email'])){ 
        $user_login = "select customer_id from customer where customer_email ='"
         .  $_SESSION['customer_email'] .
          "'"  or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $run_login = mysqli_query($con, $user_login); 
            while($p_price=mysqli_fetch_array($run_login)){

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $p_price['customer_id']; 
            }   
                    $join_query = "select customer.customer_email, item.ItemId, item.ItemPrice, cart.qty 
                    from customer, item, cart
                    where customer.customer_email = '" . $_SESSION['customer_email'] . "' AND item.ItemId = cart.orderId";

                    $run_join = mysqli_query($con, $join_query);
                    //checks error if(!$run_join)
                    if(!$run_join){
                        printf("ERROR: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
                        exit();
                    }   //END OF if(!$run_join)

                    //insert every type of item the customer has bought.
                    while($row_boat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_join)){

                        $sales_email = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
                        $sales_itemid = $row_boat['ItemId'];
                        $sales_itemprice = $row_boat['ItemPrice'];
                        $sales_qty = $row_boat['qty'];
                        $sales_total = $sales_itemprice * $sales_qty;
                        //$sales_date =
                        $insert_sales = "insert into sales (customer_email, ItemId, ItemPrice, Quantity, Total)
                         values ('$sales_email', '$sales_itemid', '$sales_itemprice', '$sales_qty', '$sales_total')";

                        $run_sales = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sales); 
                        if($run_sales){
                            mysqli_query($con, "delete * from cart where orderId = '$sales_itemid'");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("ERROR: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
                        exit();
                        }
                    }
                }
        //echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
         ?>
```

Comment: Is your `INSERT` working as you expect? Can you query your new rows in MySQL?

What is the result of this call: `mysqli_query($con, "delete * from cart where orderId = '$sales_itemid'");`? In case of failure, `mysqli_query` will return `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes, my insert query is working perfectly. And result of `mysqli_query($con, "delete * from cart where orderId = '$sales_itemid'");` is nothing. I tried printing out whether it produces an error but it didn't

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if($run_sales == TRUE){
                        mysqli_query($con, "delete * from cart where orderId = '$sales_itemid'");
                    }
```

Or:

```
if($run_sales){
$count = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
if($count>0){
    mysqli_query($con, "delete * from cart where orderId = '$sales_itemid'");
}
else{
```

If all that doesn't work, try this:

```
if($run_sales->num_rows > 0){
```

Comment: Replace your following code: $run_sales = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sales); etc...